# How to return secure https links inc# MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recently purchased a SSL certificate  from GoDaddy and was given  a secured link to my website(https:mysite)

I can access all the links on my website securely.

The problem is unless someone knows the secure link they’ll continue to use http.

I wrote the site using C# MVC .

How can I enforce that when people go to specific page views that they are accessed securely using https.

Is there something that I need to add to my controller to ensure that the web protocol is https and not http when views are returned?

Do I need to do this at the webserver level or in code?

Comment: This is something that should be configured at the web server level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the `RequireHttpsAttribute`, you could also create a [URL Rewrite rules within your web config](http://www.rsolberg.com/forcing-sslhttps-with-asp-net-mvc/)

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a global filter:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // require https for all calls
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    }
}
```

And call it from your global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    ...
}
```